# why is my form disappearing after writing a function to hide a menu

Tags: jquery, css

Hi guys i have a menu and a search form that overlap  on the menu, it is hidden by default but when i clicked the search item, the form appears, and i also wrote a line of code to hide the menu items, but both the menu items and the toggle form disappeared. Really frustrating.

In case my codes are to long and boring, which I must admit, seems to be the case here. This is a real statement of my problem- I created a form element which is hidden by default, and when a search icon is clicked, the forms shows over a menu items, and i also wrote a line of code to hide the menu item as soon as the form is shown, but the problem is that when the search icon is clicked, both the form, the search icon all disappeared, and the form is not a child element of the menu item. why will this happen, can anybody tell me why?
This are my codes:

```
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blogs
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             <li><a href="#">Guest posts</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">HTML5 articles</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">CSS3 articles</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">JavaScript articles</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connects
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Meet an Expert</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Get your respnsive website</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tech advice</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    <div class="pull-right search-case">
            <!--    <div class="search-bar-containter"> --->
                    <form class="search-form">          
                        <label class="search-label" id="search-label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></label>
                        <div class="search-input-container input-element" id="input-search">
                            <button type="button" class="for-label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                            <input  class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Enter Keyword">
                        </div>                          

                    </form>
            <!--    </div>  -->
                </div>
.navbar-nav.navbar-2  {
     margin-right:8.33333333% ;
 }

 .navbar-nav.navbar-2 > li > a {
      padding: 39px 5px;
      font-size: 1.18em;
 }

   /*Definning the search styles*/
    .pull-right.search-case {
         width: 350px;
         position: relative;
         top: -70px;
        /*right: 4.166666665%;*/
         z-index: 1000;
     }

     .search-label {
          width: 50px;
          height: 40px;
          position: absolute;
          right: -10px;
          cursor: pointer;
    }
    .search-label .glyphicon.glyphicon-search {
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-left: 15px; 
     }

      .glyphicon.glyphicon-search:hover {
          color: #fff;
      }
       .search-input {
           width: 70%;
           height: 30px;
           position: absolute;
           right: 28%;
           top: 6px;
           padding-left: 3px;
           background: #eee;
           border-top: 2px solid #32ab32;
           border-bottom: 2px solid #32ab32;
           border-left: 2px solid #32ab32;
           border-right: 2px solid #32ab32;
           backface-visibility: none;
           box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(78,78,78,0.4);

     }

       .for-label {
           width: 30%;
           height: 30px;
           position: absolute;
           right: 6px;
           top: 6px;
           background-color: rgba(180,180,180,0.9);
           border: 2px solid #32ab32;
           border-top-right-radius: 5px;
           border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;


      }
      .search-input-container {
           position: relative;
           background-color: #ffa500;
           height: 40px;
           width: 90%;
           margin-left:5px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset,
                       0 1px 0     rgba(225, 225, 225,.2);
           transition: all 2s ease-in;
           display: none;
```

}

```
      .open {
          display: block;
      }

      .search-input-container.open {
           transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
     }

     .hide {
          z-index: -1;
      }
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var label = $('.search-label').find('span');
     var inputContainer = $('.search-input-container');
     var navbar_2 = $('.navbar-2');
     label.on('click', function() {
     inputContainer.addClass('open')
     $(this).addClass('glypihicon.glypicon-times');
     navbar_2.hide();
  });
```

});

In case my codes are to long and boring, which I must admit, seems to be the case here. This is a real statement of my problem- I created a form element which is hidden by default, and when a search icon is clicked, the forms shows over a menu items, and i also wrote a line of code to hide the menu item as soon as the form is shown, but the problem is that when the search icon is clicked, both the form, the search icon all disappeared, and the form is not a child element of the menu item. why will this happen, can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some mal-formed HTML. There was a missing `span` element in the code you provided.

Working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/ts8kwu0j/

Comment: thanks for finding time to respond to my question. That must have been a typo, my problem goes like this, the form was supposed to show over the menu item when a search icon is clicked while hiding the menu, but instead, everything is hidden.